# $multiply query not working in Document DB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

We have created a documentDb instance having a 4.0.0 version. When running the query using $muliply it throws an error as Bad Query.

**Query: 'test': { $multiply: "$price", 8 }**

When checking the documentation it says the $muliply is supported. Not sure why it throws a Bad Query

Comment: Your question could be unclear. It might help if you add the exact query code you are trying to run, as well as a link to the mongodb documentation of the functionality you are trying to use (`$multiply`).

Answer (score 1):

There should be square braces encasing the field and the multiplier.

`'test': { $multiply: ["$price", 8 ]}`

If you still get an error, it might be that you are
You have to make sure that **price** is not stored as string.
You can use **$toInt** to change it to an integer or **$toDouble** if you are expecting decimals.

`'test': { $multiply: [{$toInt:"$price"}, 8 ]}`

Comment: The data is in numbers. I tried locally in mongo it works but when deploy it gives a bad query in aws.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your code, $multiply works as expected in Amazon DocumentDB:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62693003512474f1017b6ce2"),
    "name" : "prod1",
    "price" : 10
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62693009512474f1017b6ce3"),
    "name" : "prod2",
    "price" : 20
}
rs0:PRIMARY>
rs0:PRIMARY> db.collection.aggregate(
...    [
...      { $project: { _id:0, total: { $multiply: [ "$price", 8 ] } } }
...    ]
... )
{ "total" : 80 }
{ "total" : 160 }
```